# How to count positive values of last 5 rows of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do a rolling count of how many of the last 5 rows are positive in a dataframe. An example of this would be:

```
Values | Positive last 5 
------------------------
  1              1
  4              2
  -9             2
  6              3
  1              4
  -1             3
  -3             2
  4              3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create mask for compare greater values like `0` and then count `True`s by `sum` in [`Series.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html):

```
df['new'] = df['Values'].gt(0).rolling(5, min_periods=1).sum().astype(int)
print (df)
   Values  Positive last 5  new
0       1                1    1
1       4                2    2
2      -9                2    2
3       6                3    3
4       1                4    4
5      -1                3    3
6      -3                2    2
7       4                3    3
```